# Monotonicity of a discrete function

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $k_1+k_2=k$, where $k, k_1$ are all positive integers with $k_1 \ge 1$. Also let $K=\min\{k_1, \lfloor k_2/9 \rfloor +1\}$.

Define $g(x)=\max\{1 \le i \le k: \lfloor i/9 \rfloor +1=x\}, x=1, \ldots, K$.  Define for $x=1, \ldots, K$ that 
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\dfrac{\lfloor 0.1(x+g(x)) \rfloor +1}{k-x+\lfloor 0.1(x+g(x)) \rfloor +1}
\end{align*}

I would like to show that $f(x)/x$ is nondecreasing for $x=1,\ldots, K$. Can anyone give some hint?

Comment: If you're only proving it for ten points, why can't you just compute the values of $f(x)$ at each of $x =1, \ldots, 10$?

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reply. Yes, that can be done when $k$ is fixed. I did modify the question to be more general.